# Is the Google oAuth process right for react native apps

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-oauth, react-native-ios, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to put **Google signin** in place for a **react native app** in **iOS** along with the **NodeJS** backend.

The FE uses this library to configure and get **auth code** from **Google**.

*https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin*

In the backend I am verifying the auth code by sending a API to **google endpoint** with the following params:-

Backend code sample:-

```
const GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID = '123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REDACTED';
// const GOOGLE_IOS_REDIRECT_URI = 'com.smartappstechnology.kravein';
const GOOGLE_IOS_REDIRECT_URI = 'com.googleusercontent.apps.123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

export async function get_google_tokens(logging_key, { code }) {
    const GRANT_TYPE = 'authorization_code';
    try {
        const endpoint = `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id=${GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_SECRET}&code=${code}&grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}&redirect_uri=${GOOGLE_IOS_REDIRECT_URI}`;
        const response = await post_to_API(logging_key, endpoint, {});
        return response.body;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

I am getting a error like this from ***post_to_api*** response from Google:-

```
{
   "error": "invalid_request",
   "error_description": "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme in the URI"
}
```

I tried changing the redirect_uri values, but still the same issue.

I doubt whether the process I am doing itself is not correct. I experimented most of the ideas from google docs. Nothing works.

Would be helpful if anyone can refer the links of exact documentation of how this is done for react native apps in iOS with nodejs backend.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you the URI is missing a scheme. Did you try adding a scheme to the URI?

Comment: What do you meant by a scheme. Can you please give a example.

Comment: The scheme is the part like ‘https’ at the beginning of a URI

Comment: @Rinesh-Bharath you just shared your client id and client secret with the internet,  I recommend resetting the secrets on this client.

Comment: @jnpdx where can i get that scheme. Can you please paste any snapshot for reference. All i could get from google developers credentials page is Bundle_id -> com.smartappstechnology.kravein' or uri_scheme -> com.googleusercontent.apps.123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo I am resetting them.

Comment: Try adding `https://` to the beginning of your URI.